Lead converting into opportunity first
I am needing help turning a lead to opportunity first, and then once opportunity is closed, into an account?!
The conversion process is wanting to create an account, opportunity. How can I take away the account portion and just leave the opportunity conversion just the option?

Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. It's important to include a lot of details here, and to show us what you've researched and tried so far. The common line is that we're here to help you work through problems, but not do all of the work for you. Even if what you have doesn't work, it gives people a glimpse into your mindset and helps people address specific issues that you're running into. If you're getting an error message somewhere, be sure to include the full error, verbatim, and with the stack trace. You can [edit] your question to add additional details.

That said, pretty sure that the standard lead conversion process isn't going to be able to do what you want here. You're going to need something like a Flow (declarative; i.e. "clicks, not code") or a Trigger to do the "create an Account after the Opportunity has closed" part.

Not possible w/ OOTB LeadConversion process and also requirement is counterintuitive since Opportunity.Account is a required field on page layout
